# About data types with for loops with commas

Tags: c, for-loop

In C if you have the following code:

```
for (size_t x, y = someValue; y > 0; y -= x, ptr1 += x, ptr2 += x) 
{
        // do stuff
}
```

Will the variable y also be of the type size_t or would it be an int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a declaration of

```
int a,b,c;
size_t x,y,z;
```

means that all of a,b,c are same type (int) as are x,y,z (size_t)

The declaration inside a for-loop is no different -- and in your example both x and y are of type size_t

**however** in your example `x` is not initialized (only y is set to `somevalue`) -- and unless the body of the loops set it to something you will find that `y -= x` is going to give you <s>random</s> undefined results.

Comment: random isn't the best word, undefined would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the same as if you do:

```
size_t x, y = someValue;
```

In such situation both x and y are `size_t` and `y = someValue`.

Answer (score 0):

`y` would be the same time as `x`, `size_t`, just as it would with the same expression outside of a `for` loop:

```
size_t x, y = someValue;
```

One simple way to find out is to just print the size of the variables for yourself, as long as `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(int)` (if it is, just change `size_t` to `char` to make the difference evident).

Answer (score 0):

In your example yes; `x` and `y` are both of type `size_t`.  However, to add to your confusing, consider declaration:

```
int *x, y;
```

In this case `x` is a pointer to `int`, but `y` is just a `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (size_t x, y = someValue; y > 0; y -= x, ptr1 += x, ptr2 += x) 
    {
            // do stuff
    }
```

1. x and y are both "size_t" (usually 4 bytes on most platforms)
2. y is initialized to "someValue".
3. x, however, is UNINITIALIZED.

`int 
    main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {

      size_t x, y = 1;

      printf ("x=%d, y=%d, sizeof(x)=%d...\n",
        x, y, sizeof (x));

      return 0; 
    }`

x=4201366, y=1, sizeof(x)=4...